# Employers Resume Search Options

Tags: support, jobs

I am considering signing up for Employer Resume search features.  Do you offer any trials to see if candidates search features work for us?

Answer (score 4):

If you send us an email to careers@stackoverflow.com with your contact information, I can have a sales rep contact you.

Thanks!